# Как заставить общаться две программы на python

Tags: python

У меня есть условные две программы на питоне. Мне нужно чтобы они могли передавать данные между собой. Обе программы работают на одном компе/сервере.
Заранее прошу прощения если это глупый вопрос, но то что я смог нагуглить по итогу было не то.
По возможности хотелось бы увидеть документацию, чтобы самому разобраться.

Comment: По фразе «межпроцессное взаимодействие» гуглятся тонны инфы

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html

Answer (score 4):

Представлю Вам самый банальный пример взаимодействия двух приложений:

Обмен данных посредством файлов - в каталоге 4 файла. file(1/2).py и fileMSG(1/2).txt

Код file(1/2).py:

```
import threading, time

def messageGetter():
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            f = open("file(1/2)MSG.txt", "r")
            msg = f.read()
            
            if msg != None and msg !='':
                print(msg)
            f.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

thread = threading.Thread(target=messageGetter, args=())

thread.start()

while True:
    msgTo = input('Your message: ')
    fo = open("file(1/2)MSG.txt", 'w')
    fo.write(msgTo)
    fo.close()
```

Как видите обе программы постоянно проверяют файл, а также отсылают данные в другой файл, когда этого требует юзер

По аналогии строится почти любая система, например через Базу Данных или API (что лучше)

Например, API за 5 минут вы можете написать с помощью [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)

Также интересным, но более сложным решением будет использовать [Propan](https://habr.com/ru/articles/737536/)

Comment: Это жестокое обращение с накопителем

Comment: Проще объяснить +- адекватную работу общения двух приложений не получится, поэтому я выбрал вариант с демонстрации обмена сообщениями посредством файла. В любом случае, идея везде такая же, но лучше. Возможно, можно было вызывать методы напрямую из процесса, но я это практиковал пару раз в ВУЗе на C++ и более никогда не использовал. Если Вы знаете как реализовать это в Python, Было бы интересно взглянуть. Все же, считаю практического применения это в 99% случаев не несет

Comment: Для задачи «передавать данные между собой» достаточно банальных stdin/stdout. Хотя, конечно, без дополнительных уточнений от автора о том, что конкретно ему нужно, непонятно что лучше использовать

Answer (score 0):

Вообще способов межпросессного взаимодействия (Inter-process communication (IPC)) более чем куча...

- каналы (sdtin/stdout)
- разделяемая память
- примитивы синхронизации (именованные семафоры/мьютексы)
- буффера FIFO в *nix системах
- именованные трубы (named pipes) в Windows
- сокеты
- ... различная экзотика типа Dbus, событий в БД и т.д.

Простейший пример взаимодействия через буффера fifo в linux

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import errno

FIFO = '/tmp/my_fifo'
try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
except OSError as oe:
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

print("Opening FIFO...")
with open(FIFO) as fifo:
    print("FIFO opened")
    while True:
        data = fifo.read()
        if len(data) == 0:
            print("Writer closed")
            fifo.close()
            os.unlink(FIFO)
            break
        print('Read: "{0}"'.format(data))
```

Запускаем:

> ./fifo.py &

и пробуем что-то записать в буффер

> echo hello! >/tmp/my_fifo

получаем:

> Read: "test
> "
> Writer closed

Винды под рукой нет, но примеров с именованными трубами (named pipes) в интернетах полно... к примеру вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542644/python-and-windows-named-pipes